# Interpret the clustering results of Weka to measure the performance

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, weka

I'm having the Boston dataset, where it's class variable in the housing price. So I think regression is more suitable for this dataset, so we can predictions.

I'm using Weka for this. I used several regression algorithms and could evaluate the performance of regression.

I just wanted to check whether clustering works with my data set. These are the results I obtained.

```
=== Run information ===

Scheme:       weka.clusterers.SimpleKMeans -init 0 -max-candidates 100 -periodic-pruning 10000 -min-density 2.0 -t1 -1.25 -t2 -1.0 -N 2 -A "weka.core.EuclideanDistance -R first-last" -I 500 -num-slots 1 -S 10
Relation:     housing-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.InterquartileRange-Rfirst-last-O3.0-E6.0-weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.RemoveWithValues-S0.0-C15-Llast-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove-R15-16-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove-R4,8-9
Instances:    438
Attributes:   11
              CRIM
              ZN
              INDUS
              NOX
              RM
              AGE
              TAX
              PTRATIO
              B
              LSTAT
              class
Test mode:    split 66% train, remainder test


=== Clustering model (full training set) ===


kMeans
======

Number of iterations: 6
Within cluster sum of squared errors: 144.78333527946944

Initial starting points (random):

Cluster 0: 0.15445,25,5.13,0.453,6.145,29.2,284,19.7,390.68,6.86,23.3
Cluster 1: 7.83932,0,18.1,0.655,6.209,65.4,666,20.2,396.9,13.22,21.4

Missing values globally replaced with mean/mode

Final cluster centroids:
                         Cluster#
Attribute    Full Data          0          1
               (438.0)    (286.0)    (152.0)
============================================
CRIM            3.1711     0.2599     8.6489
ZN              7.3459      11.25          0
INDUS          11.3185     7.2142    19.0411
NOX             0.5579     0.4941     0.6781
RM              6.3063     6.4543     6.0279
AGE            69.9447     58.979    90.5776
TAX           400.7694   298.4685   593.2566
PTRATIO        18.4845    17.9395    19.5099
B             358.3076   389.1012    300.367
LSTAT          12.4776      9.714    17.6776
class          22.8628    25.8227    17.2934




Time taken to build model (full training data) : 0.01 seconds

=== Model and evaluation on test split ===

kMeans
======

Number of iterations: 3
Within cluster sum of squared errors: 101.20987958357911

Initial starting points (random):

Cluster 0: 5.73116,0,18.1,0.532,7.061,77,666,20.2,395.28,7.01,25
Cluster 1: 0.18159,0,7.38,0.493,6.376,54.3,287,19.6,396.9,6.87,23.1

Missing values globally replaced with mean/mode

Final cluster centroids:
                         Cluster#
Attribute    Full Data          0          1
               (289.0)     (99.0)    (190.0)
============================================
CRIM            3.4497     9.5404     0.2762
ZN              7.7699          0    11.8184
INDUS          11.4102    19.1316      7.387
NOX              0.557     0.6773     0.4943
RM              6.2967     5.9688     6.4676
AGE             70.274    90.6424    59.6611
TAX            397.391   587.0505   298.5684
PTRATIO        18.5235    19.4384    18.0468
B             357.8081    300.728   387.5498
LSTAT          12.7507    17.9897    10.0209
class             22.9    16.9687    25.9905




Time taken to build model (percentage split) : 0 seconds

Clustered Instances

0       52 ( 35%)
1       97 ( 65%)
```

I used 2 clusters. What I need to know is, how can I interpret these results and how to evaluate the performance, since I do not have a class variable. Kindly give your input to understand this

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation of your results depends on what you want to achieve. What do you cant to achieve by clustering your data? If you want to make predictions of house prices you should use regression models, as you already mentioned yourself.

In general, the performance of a clustering algorithm can be measured for instance by inter- and intra-cluster similarities, i.e. whether the points that belong to the same cluster are similar to each other and different to points in another cluster.